# What do c and s mean as parameters to matplotlib's plot function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code from a Jupyter notebook:

```
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude",
             s=housing["population"]/100, alpha=0.4, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
             c="median_house_value", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), colorbar=True,
             sharex=False)
```

I can't seem to find what is meant by the parameters `s` and `c` anywhere in the documentation. Can someone please explain?

Comment: c is for color values, s is for marker size. Read the documentation of matplotlib scatter plot

Comment: Maybe look the doc https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot ;)

Comment: Nitpicking: it's the dataframe's method `.plot()`, not `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` (that has not, of course, a parameter `kind` in its signature)

Comment: @azro I checked this out but I couldn't figure out where 'c' and 's' are mentioned as parameters

Comment: Color or c : in the other parameter table below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`housing.plot` with `kind='scatter'` is a [pandas function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) which passes most of its parameters to matplotlib's [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). When a parameter is given as a string (e.g. "median_house_value"), pandas interprets this string as a pandas column name, and the values of that column are passed to matplotlib.

So, `c="median_house_value"` gives the values of that column as a list to the `c=` parameter of matplotlib's scatter. There `c=` is shorthand for `color=`. When getting a list of numbers as a color, matplotlib first normalizes the list to values between 0 and 1, and then looks up that value in its colormap.

The `s=housing["population"]/100` gives a list of each value of the "population" column divided by 100 to matplotlib's `s=` parameter. This defines the size of the markers, where the size is interpreted as the area of the marker, not its diameter.

Note the awkward `**kwargs` in the documentation. This is a list of additional parameters which are passed to deeper functions, e.g. to the function that plots lines.